# How can I feed data one by one to train with tensorflow 2.0 ver

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have work on Autoencoder typed model with the attention method. Around 10000 batches of data are fed into the model and each batch contains 30 images (30 is the "step_size" in ConvLSTM) with a shape of (5, 5, 3 [R,G,B]).

Therefore, the array is of shape `(10000, 30, 5, 5, 3)`  (batch_size, step_size, image_height, image_width, scale).

I intentionally made an output array shape as `(1,5,5,3)`, because each image has to be handled independently to apply attention method to.

When I link all operations with `tf.keras.Model` such that its input has the shape of `(10000,30,5,5,3)` and the output shape of `(1,5,5,3)`.

```
history = model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size = 1, epochs = 3)
```

I am trying to modify arguments in Model module, but it seems not working because the output shape is not the same as the input.

Are there any possible ways to feed data one by one?

I am eventually running a code something like:

```
model = keras.Model(intput, output)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss= tf.keras.losses.MSE)

history = model.fit(train_data, train_data, batch_size = 1, epochs = 3)
```

Comment: Could you provide the source code, or at least the summary of your model?

Comment: why don't you like your own solution with `batch_size = 1`?

Comment: If you're willing to mess around and can afford slower training speeds, you could unstack the 5D vector into a list of 4D vectors, attend to each element, and then stack the results.

Comment: @RuslanS. batch_size =1 just simply unpack samples into 1 batch size, ex) (10000, 30, 5, 5, 3) becomes (1, 30, 5, 5, 3) which is not equal to (1,5,5,3).

Comment: @Susmit Agrawal  Could you specify how to do that with model.fit?

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen Please refer to [here](https://github.com/pkucyh/MSCRED-1/blob/master/code/MSCRED_TF.py)

Comment: @BrianLee From the comments, I think you are misunderstanding here. Normally, the input for the attention is a sequence (in your case (30,5,5,3) ) and its output is (1,5,5,3), which is the weighted sum of 30 step size. Therefore, their shapes must be different from each other.

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen You are right. What I want to do eventually with this model is to create reconstructed matrices, then what should I feed to `model.fit` for x and y?

Comment: Thus, the size of the output y after the attention would be smaller than x (1 and 30). I don't think it can be considered as AE here. Can you provide your intuition of why you want to apply attention to your model for this task in the question?

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen I am trying to use window sliding method over time-series data for a certain period by calculating the correlation matrix for each window at each step. When I overlap three windows, those can be stacked to 3D like RGB data which can be used for the ConvLSTM model plus attention method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could've done with GradientTape, feeding one by one.

```
def train(loss, model, opt, x_inp):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss(model, x_inp), model.trainable_variables)
    gradient_variables = zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(gradient_variables)


opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(train_log_dir)

epochs = 3

with train_summary_writer.as_default():
  with tf.summary.record_if(True):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
      for train_id in range(0, len(batch_data)):
          x_inp = np.reshape(np.asarray(batch_data), [-1, step_max, sensor_n, sensor_n, scale_n])
          train(loss, model, opt, x_inp)
          loss_values = loss(model, x_inp)
          reconstructed = np.reshape(model(x_inp), [1, sensor_n, sensor_n, scale_n])
      print("loss : {}".format(loss_values.numpy()))
```